Example of a resolution arising from "relations between relations"
One often sees resolutions of objects in some abelian category motivated as follows (see e.g. the book by Rotman on homological algebra):
If we want to understand an $R$-module $M$, we can express it by "generators" as follows: Find a surjective map $\pi: R^{\oplus n} \to M$ and write
$$ \ker(\pi) \to R^{\oplus n} \to M \to 0. $$
Then we have expressed $M$ by $n$ generators (the standard basis vectors in $R^{\oplus n}$) and their relations inside $M$ by $\ker(\pi)$. If $R$ is not PID, then $\ker(\pi)$ need not be free over $R$, so we can do the same game again: find a surjection $\pi_1 : R^{\oplus n_1} \to \ker(\pi)$, and extend the above sequence to
$$ \ker(\pi_1) \to R^{\oplus n_1} \to \ker(\pi) \to R^{\oplus n} \to M \to 0. $$
Do this until a kernel $\ker(\pi_N)$ is reached which is free.
What would an example be of such a resolution?
I so far only have seen examples where either the resolution is of length 2 (i.e. an exact sequence), or all of the terms are already free (or non-free). So I am explicitly looking for a resolution where one has the alternating behaviour of free (the $R^{\oplus n_j})$ and non-free (the kernels $\ker(\pi_j)$).

I haven't put too much thought into this, but perhaps the following works: Consider the sequence
$$
\cdots \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4 \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} 2 \cdot \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} 2 \cdot \mathbb{Z}/4 \to 0
$$
of the $\mathbb{Z}/4$-module $M := 2 \cdot \mathbb{Z}/4$, where $m$ denotes multiplication by $2$. Notice that $\mathbb{Z}/4$ is free as a module over itself, but $\ker (m) = 2 \cdot \mathbb{Z}/4$ is not flat over $\mathbb{Z}/4$, so in particular not free.
P.S.: Grüße aus Bonn ;)

Yes, this works and it is indeed a standard example of a long exact sequence... Grüße aus Würzburg!
